# Is it possible to translate only special characters to unicode?

Tags: java, unicode

I have text files that contains polish characters (like 'ń') but I can't display them like this (i get '?' in places of this special characters). My solution is to use unicode codes like

```
&#x0144;
```

for 'ń' and so on, for example polish word "koń" would look like

```
ko&#x0144;
```

When I used

```
org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4("&#x0144;")
```

I get String containing "ń", so i thought escapeHtml4 method for "ń" will give me String containing

```
"&#x0144;"
```

as a result but i get "ń" again. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Where do you try to display these characters? How?

Comment: Im using velocity to create email templates with html. When im not using html tags polish chars works well, but when I turn on html i get these '?'. I tried changing velocity properties and using html meta tag but it didnt work.

Comment: *"My solution is to use unicode codes like"* The *correct* solution is to ensure that all of the components in your web stack understand the text encoding that you're using and serve the HTML accordingly. More: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: I suspect you need to set the `Content-Type` MIME header correctly in your email to tell the email client you have sent utf-8.

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Provided, of course, that he/she is sending UTF-8 and not Windows-1252 or ISO-8859 or...

Comment: Yes, i'm using utf-8. It's all about setting email header? My email service implementation is hidden so I didnt think about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you're using UTF-8 and sending email. You'll need to tell the email layer to include

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
```

...in the email headers; sadly, email clients tend to ignore the equivalent `meta` tag in the email's HTML. [More in this article](https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/the_importance_of_content-type_character_encoding_in_html_emails).